# Send two arrays or array with variable via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have some code that work, but I need to add some variable to the data sent by ajax.
I know, I can put this variable in the array sended, but it's no good for me.
I want to add **+'&count='+'second'**

Maybe I can send second array, but how?

```
var arr = new Array(1,2,3,4);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl + "search/simple_filter",
    data: {arr: arr}+'&count='+'second',
    success: function (data) {
        if (!data) console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = new Array(1,2,3,4);
             $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: baseUrl + "search/simple_filter",
             data: {'arr': arr, 'count': second},
             success: function (data) {
             if (!data) 
             console.log(data);
             }
             });
```

Answer (score 4):

Expand your base object, like so:

```
  data: {arr: arr, count : 'second'}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a query string parameter in a POST request you would add it to the URL:

```
url: baseUrl + "search/simple_filter?count=" + second,
data: { arr: arr },
```

I assume that you want to use the value of the variable `second`, not the string `"second"`.

If you want to add the parameter in the POST data, and not as a query string parameter, you would add it to the object for the `data` property:

```
url: baseUrl + "search/simple_filter",
data: { arr: arr, count: second },
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add that to the POST URL and not the body:

```
 var arr = new Array(1,2,3,4);
     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: baseUrl + "search/simple_filter"+'&count='+'second',
          data: {arr: arr},
          success: function (data) {
             if (!data) 
              console.log(data);
         }
      });
```